# how i can achieve this vertical cups slides design in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack

I'm trying to use `BoxWithConstraints` but it doesn't make it right cause it's `List` of cups.

I also use Space between with `Modifier`, which does not give me the design I want. how can I achieve this? I want a list that I can swipe between them.

Expected Outputs:

[image: preview]

Comment: Do you hve images of the three cups

Comment: you can simply use the image!
but in some wired case you must decrease size and add padding from bottom to cups.